# Displaying coded names in the grid

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, esri-grid-format

I am trying to display coded names (TREE_SPECIES) in the grid, instead of values using ArcGIS JavaScript.

It says updateFeature is undefined. Below is my entire code, which I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <title>BGSU Memorial Tree Listing</title>
        <script src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.highlight-4.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">
        <style>           
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
           h3 {
                color:#f89b35;
                text-align:center;
            }
            h4 {
                color:#4f2c1d;
                text-align:center;    
            }           
            #grid {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }          
            .field-OBJECTID {
                width: 10px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }          
            .field-MEMORIAL {
                width: 20px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }    
            .field-DONOR {
                width: 20px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }                   
           .field-MEMNUM {
                width: 10px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }                      
            .field-PLINK {
                width: 10px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }          
            .field-TLINK {
                width: 10px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }            
            .field-TREE_SPECIES {
                width: 10px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }      
            .field-TREE_VARIETY {
                width: 10px;
                font-size: .80em;
                font-weight: normal;
            }

            #grid .dgrid-row-odd {
                background: #F2F5F9;
            }

          .highlight {
                background-color: yellow; }

        </style>

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"> </script>
<script>           
            var grid;
            var i;
        var updateFeature;
            require([            // required modules
             "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
             "dgrid/Grid", 
             "dojo/store/Memory", 
             "dojo/_base/array", 
             "esri/map",
             "esri/tasks/query", 
             "esri/tasks/QueryTask", 
             "dojo/_base/declare", 
             "dojo/on", 
             "dojo/number",
             "dojo/dom", 
             "dojo/dom-style",
             "dojo/ready"
             ], 
            function(
            FeatureLayer,
            Grid,
            Memory,
            array, 
            map,
            Query, 
            QueryTask, 
            declare,
            on, 
            number, 
            dom, 
            domStyle,
            TREE_VARIETY,
            MEMORIAL_TREE_DONOR,
            ready
            ){
                var form = dom.byId("text"),
        //create the grid
                 grid = new Grid({
            bufferRows: Infinity, // all the data is available in the grid
                    columns: { //defines the cloumns 
                        OBJECTID: "OBJECTID",
                        MEMORIAL: "MEMORIAL",
                        DONOR: "DONOR",
                        MEMNUM: "MEMNUM",
                        TREE_SPECIES: "SPECIES",
                        TREE_VARIETY: "VARIETY",
                        TLINK: {
                            label: "TLINK",
                            formatter: makeLink1
                        },
                        PLINK: {
                            label: "PLINK",
                            formatter: makeLink2
                        } 
                    },

               },"grid");

                // create feature layer
                var layer = new FeatureLayer("https://gistest2.bgsu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/MemorialTrees/MemorialTEST/MapServer/0", {
                outFields: ["*"]

                });

                layer.on("load", function(){
                 var query = new Query();
                 query.where = "1=1";
                 query.outFields = ["*"];
                /*  for (var i = 0; i < layer.fields.length; i++) {
                     console.debug(layer.fields[i].domain);
                     var updateFeature = layer.fields[i].domain;
                     }  */
                layer.queryFeatures(query, function(featureSet){
                 // executes on success
                console.log("query featureSet", featureSet);
        if (featureSet.length>0)
            var updateFeature = featureSet[0].getlayer().name();
                populateTable(featureSet);      
                    }, function(error){
                console.log("query error", error);     
                    });                    
                });


                function populateTable(featureSet){ 
                    var data = array.map(featureSet.features, function(feature){
                        return {
                            "OBJECTID": feature.attributes.OBJECTID,
                            "MEMORIAL": feature.attributes.MEMORIAL,
                            "DONOR": feature.attributes.MEMORIAL_TREE_DONOR,
                            "MEMNUM": feature.attributes.MEMNUM,
                            "PLINK": feature.attributes.PLINK,
                            "TLINK": feature.attributes.TLINK,
                "TREE_SPECIES":updateFeature.atrributes.TREE_SPECIES,
                            "TREE_VARIETY": feature.attributes.TREE_VARIETY
                        };

                    });
                    grid.renderArray(data);
             }         

                    function makeLink1(url){
                     console.log("make link", url);
                     return '<a href="Photo.html?value= '+url+'&DONOR='+DONOR+'&TreeVariety='+TreeVariety+'">' +'Photo'+ '</a>';
                } 
                    function makeLink2(url){
                    console.log("make link", url);
                    return '<a href="Map.html?value='+url+' ">' +'Plaque'+ '</a>';
                }
            });
        </script>
        </head>

    <body>

        <h3 align="absmiddle" >  BGSU Memorial Tree Locations </h3>
        <h4 align="center" > <i>Listings | <a target="_self" href="locations.html">Locations</a></i> </h4>    
        <br>
        <div align="center">
    <form>
        <h4>Enter a name, matching result will be highlighted: <input type="text" id="text" /> 
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:void($('body').removeHighlight().highlight(document.getElementById('text').value));  return false;"> Search</a> </h4>
        </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="grid">
        </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Layer doesn't have a *method* called `name`, but it does have a *property* called `name`, so replace this line

`var updateFeature = featureSet[0].getlayer().name();`

with

`var updateFeature = featureSet[0].getlayer().name;`